# while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) doesn't work in second time

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ... ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { first time used; }
...
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { second time used; }
```

In second time it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: why would you want to run it two times...?

Comment: Can you please write what you get in $query ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can't you store the data you need in an array, which is easier to reuse?

Comment: (tongue-in-cheek) Why do you think the loop *stops* the first time...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the internal data pointer has reached its end. To reread the query, either rewind the pointer with `mysql_data_seek()`, or reissue the query.

Answer (score 6):

A MySQL result resource has an internal pointer, much like a PHP array, and when you have run through it once, the pointer is at the end. You can reset the data pointer using [`mysql_data_seek()`](http://php.net/mysql-data-seek):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  // First time used
}
mysql_data_seek($query, 0);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  // Second time used
}
```

...*but* what is arguably a better/more "standard" approach is to run through the pointer once, store the results in a temporary array and then you can release the memory used by the results and loop the data as an array:

```
// Do the query
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ... ");

// Cache the results in an array
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $results[] = $row;
}

// Free the result resource
mysql_free_result($query);

foreach ($results as $row) {
  // First time used
}
foreach ($results as $row) {
  // Second time used
}
```

As a side note, it is more resource efficient to use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysql-fetch-assoc) or [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/mysql-fetch-row) - almost every use case only calls for `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, it is very uncommon that you indexed keys for a MySQL result, and even less common that you need both indexed *and* associative.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work the second time because you have already retrieved all of the rows. Therefore it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the result pointer to the beginning of the result set before looping the second time using [mysql_data_seek()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php)

```
mysql_data_seek($query,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've retrieved all the rows so you'll have to run another query or you can shove the values from your first loop into an array and then output that array for the second time you want to display the same data.

Or use mysql_data_seek()