# While loop outputs empty select boxes

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli, while-loop

I have two sql-queries:

1. Gives the number of employees associated with the project. For instance 4 in this case.
2. Gives the names and id's of the employees.

I want my code to output 4 select boxes with all the names of the employees in it. As `<option></option>` tags.

My current code gives 4 select boxes. Only the first one is filled with the names of the employes which is correct. The next three is empty `<select></select>` tags

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","portefoejlestyring");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");



$query= "
select 
medarbejdere.navn as medarbejderNavn,
medarbejdere.id as medarbejderId,
projekt.id as projectId

from projekt_has_medarbejdere

join projekt on projekt.id = projekt_has_medarbejdere.projekt_ref
join medarbejdere on medarbejdere.id = projekt_has_medarbejdere.bruger_ref

where projekt.id = '$search'

"; 

$queryMedarbejder= "
select 
medarbejdere.navn as medarbejderNavn,
medarbejdere.id as medarbejderId

from medarbejdere
"; 

$x = 2;
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);  
        $resultMedarbejder=mysqli_query($con,$queryMedarbejder);

 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

                    echo "<select class='selectpicker form-control' name='medarbejder[]'>";     

            while ($rowMedarbejder=mysqli_fetch_array($resultMedarbejder,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<option value='$rowMedarbejder[medarbejderId]' name='medarbejder'>$rowMedarbejder[medarbejderNavn]</option>";

            } 

         echo "</select>";

            }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you please show the `mysql query` or complete code?

Comment: @mageDev0688 Post updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the issue because the inner loop is already at the end when you start the second iteration of the outer loop. MySQL fetch does not go back to the start of the inner loop automatically on each round of the outer loop.

Put the results of the inner loop into an array first, then you can loop through the array as many times as you like.

Comment: Thank you very much. The solution was to put the result into an array and loop through it with foreach. For the outer loop I used for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

probably a duplicate when you rephrase the question [while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) doesn't work in second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698944/whilerow-mysql-fetch-arrayquery-doesnt-work-in-second-time)

P.S. i was unable to comment,so posting as answer